# How to save answer of quiz app in object and retrieve

Tags: android, object, radio-button

I am developing an study app which includes quiz functionality. I can retrieve questions and also it is saving in object. I have an Next and previous button to see next or previous question. It is also working fine. But i need your help in saving selected answer in object. If user press previous button then selected answer should be selected in radio button. And if user change the selected answer then it should updated in object also.

**TestQuestion**

```
 ArrayList<QuestionObject> questionObject;
 ArrayList<String> answerObject;
 int position = 0;

 if (position == 0){
        btnPrev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = position+1;
          //  txtQuestionNo.setText(String.valueOf(questionObject.get(position).getId()));
            txtQuestionNo.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
            txtQuestion.setText(questionObject.get(position).getQuestion());
            optionA.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption1());
            optionB.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption2());
            optionC.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption3());
            optionD.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption4());

            if (position>0){
                btnPrev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (position+1 == questionObject.size()){
                btnNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }



        }
    });
    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = position-1;
          //  txtQuestionNo.setText(String.valueOf(questionObject.get(position).getId()));
            txtQuestionNo.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
            txtQuestion.setText(questionObject.get(position).getQuestion());
            optionA.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption1());
            optionB.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption2());
            optionC.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption3());
            optionD.setText(questionObject.get(position).getOption4());


            if (position == 0){
                btnPrev.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            if (position+1 != questionObject.size()){
                btnNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


        }
    });
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(TestQuestion.this, TestResult.class));
        }
    });

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            answerObject = new ArrayList<>();
            String ans = "";
            switch (checkedId){
                case R.id.optionA:
                    ans = "A";
                    break;
                case R.id.optionB:
                    ans = "B";
                    break;
                case R.id.optionC:
                    ans = "C";
                    break;
                case R.id.optionD:
                    ans = "D";
                    break;
            }

            answerObject.add(ans);


        }
    });
```

**QuestionObject**

```
public class QuestionObject {
private int id;
private String question;
private String option1;
private String option2;
private String option3;
private String option4;


public QuestionObject(JSONObject jsonObject){
    if (jsonObject == null) return;
    this.id = jsonObject.optInt("id");
    this.question = jsonObject.optString("Question");
    this.option1 = jsonObject.optString("option1");
    this.option2 = jsonObject.optString("option2");
    this.option3 = jsonObject.optString("option3");
    this.option4 = jsonObject.optString("option4");
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
    this.question = question;
}

public String getOption1() {
    return option1;
}

public void setOption1(String option1) {
    this.option1 = option1;
}

public String getOption2() {
    return option2;
}

public void setOption2(String option2) {
    this.option2 = option2;
}

public String getOption3() {
    return option3;
}

public void setOption3(String option3) {
    this.option3 = option3;
}

public String getOption4() {
    return option4;
}

public void setOption4(String option4) {
    this.option4 = option4;
} }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your questionObject Object looks like.

You have a variable `position` where you store the current selected object index that is known outside the listner methods.

You can do something like this:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        answerObject = new ArrayList<>();
        String ans = "";
        switch (checkedId){
            case R.id.optionA:
                ans = "A";
                break;
            case R.id.optionB:
                ans = "B";
                break;
            case R.id.optionC:
                ans = "C";
                break;
            case R.id.optionD:
                ans = "D";
                break;
        }

        answerObject.add(ans);
        questionObject.get(position).getQuestion().setAnswer(answerObject); // I added this line

    }
});
```

Check out this line:

```
questionObject.get(position).setAnswer(answerObject);
```

Of course that assumes that your questionObject has the method `setAnswer(ArrayList<> answer)`.

**UPDATE**

If you can't modify your questionObject, create a custom answerObject.

```
public class AnswerObject {
     private int questionId;
     private String answer;

     public AnswerObject (int questionId, String answer){

         this.questionId = questionId;
         this.answer = answer;
     }

 }

// Outside the listeners
ArrayList<AnswerObject> answerObjects = new ArrayList<>();


// Inside your setOnCheckedChangeListener
AnswerObject answerObject = new AnswerObject(questionObject.get(position).getId(), ans);
answerObjects.add(answerObject);
```

After the test is finished you can use the answerObjects array to post all your answers with the reference to `question IID` to the API endpoint.

Comment: i cant modify questionObject data. I have to store selected answer in answerObject and i have to send this data to the server back with respect that question at the end of test.

Comment: Where is your API Client code? You need the reference to the question object otherwise the API endpoint can't handle the answer correctly. You can't store only the answer with no reference to which question the answer should answer. And why you can't modify the questionObject data?

Comment: Ok i got it how to save it but why u use getOption1() ? there is 4 options.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest form (If you don't want to use databases and all), I would suggest Gson and SharedPreferences to save and restore your data.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:xx'
SharedPreferences  prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

When you want to save:

```
Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(theObjectYouWantToSave);
prefsEditor.putString("MyObject", json);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

And when you want to restore your data:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = prefs.getString("MyObject", "");
MyObject obj = gson.fromJson(json, MyObject.class);
```